# Can an IoT Edge module twin's properties be used for message enrichment?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

IoT Hub has the ability to enrich messages prior to being sent to an endpoint.  It appears that the device twin's information can be added, but I don't see anything about the module twins online.

The use case here would be we will likely version a module data model contained within the messages at some point in the future.  We would like to enrich the messages sent to endpoints with metadata about the state of the module it came from.

Another option that doesn't seem to exist is the ability to update device twin properties on deployment.  Were this doable, then potentially we could update a modules version information at the device twin level.

Is this the wrong way to think about twins?  Aka were such functionality even available, would the enrichment take the point in time twin reported value?  Could there even be any guarantee that the twin has the correct reported value at the time the module sent the message?  It that is the case, is the only real reliable way to send metadata about a module's message is within the message itself?

Comment: I don't think "IoTEdge module" enrichment supported. add in User Voice https://feedback.azure.com/forums/907045-azure-iot-edge

Answer (score 1):

If you send an event from within a module using a module client, the keyword `$twin` in the message enrichment will refer to the module twin.